# TensorFlow Iris load_csv_with_header( )

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

In the TensorFlow quick start tutorial which folder am I suppose to put the iris training/test csv files as to let me use this code. I'm specifically having problems using the load_csv_with_header module and being new to programming I'm at a lost when they say "Place these files in the same directory as your Python code." To my eyes there appears to be a several directories which may satisfy this but at last no results. I've also tried typing getcwd() into the interpreter but it says no module defined. I'm using python 2.7 with the most current version of andaconda to do this.

```
# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have saved the tutorial code in your computer as **tf_learn_tutorial.py**
in a folder named **tutorial1**. Then you should make sure you download and save the **iris_training.csv** file and **iris_test.csv** file in the same folder named **tutorial1** where your **.py** file exists.

After which the folder **tutorial1** on your computer should have (at least) these three files:

- tf_learn_tutorial.py
- iris_training.csv
- iris_test.csv

To make it even simpler for you to quick start the tutorial,

**Step 1**: Download this [file (tf_learn_tutorial.py)](http://pastebin.com/raw/C7J2Nm6c) and save it as **tf_learn_tutorial.py** on your computer in a folder named **tutorial1** anywhere on your hard disk as you like.

**Step 2**: Download this [file (iris_training.csv)](http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv) and save it on your computer in the same folder as above named **tutorial1**.

**Step 3**: Download this [file (iris_test.csv)](http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv) and save it on your computer in the same folder as above named **tutorial1**.

**Step 4**: Run the **tf_learn_tutorial.py** file from the **tutorial1** directory:

`python tf_learn_tutorial.py`.